# sitemesh with multiple decorator files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sitemesh

I want multiple decorators, as documented here: https://github.com/sitemesh/sitemesh2. I provide multiple decorators in decorators.xml but the main decorator gets applied to every file in my project. 
E.g. my decorators looks like this:

```
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/decorators">
    <decorator name="main" page="main.jspx">
       <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
    <decorator name="other" page="other.jspx">
        <pattern>/spring/other/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>
```

And both `/spring/some/page.jspx` and `/spring/other/page.jspx` both render with the `main.jspx' template.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I know the documentation example contradicts this idea, but if you need something to try -- try re-ordering your decorators like so:

```
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/decorators"> 
    <decorator name="other" page="other.jspx"> 
        <pattern>/spring/other/*</pattern> 
    </decorator>
    <decorator name="main" page="main.jspx"> 
       <pattern>/*</pattern> 
    </decorator> 
</decorators>
```

From memory I thought Sitemesh used the *first* matching decorator pattern, and with the order you've specified that would always be the "main" decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/decorators"> 
    <decorator name="main" page="main.jspx"> 
       <pattern>/spring/main/*</pattern> 
    </decorator> 
    <decorator name="other" page="other.jspx"> 
        <pattern>/spring/other/*</pattern> 
    </decorator> 
</decorators>
```

and tell me if it worked.

Comment: that didn't work. actually I've tried a bunch of things and the only thing that works (for any template) is `/*` or `/context*`. So for example any pattern like `/context/x/*` doesn't get applied.